# what is impl Trait + 'lifetime

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, traits, lifetime, static-dispatch

I am reading the [async book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/01_chapter.html).  In [section `async lifetimes`](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html#async-lifetimes) there is a code snippet whose grammar I am not familiar with:

```rust
fn foo_expanded<'a>(x: &'a u8) -> impl Future<Output = u8> + 'a {
    async move { *x }
}
```

In `impl Future<Output = u8> + 'a`, what is `impl Trait + 'lifetime` here?

Update: I am more asking what it is instead of the lifetime logic explanation. A definition from the official doc will be
much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is `impl Trait + 'lifetime` here?

It is an [Impl trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html), here particularly used as an abstract return type

> #### Impl trait
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> ImplTraitType : impl TypeParamBounds
> ImplTraitTypeOneBound : impl TraitBound
> ```
>
> `impl` Trait provides ways to specify unnamed but concrete types that
> implement a specific trait. It can appear in two sorts of places:
> argument position (where it can act as an anonymous type parameter to
> functions), and return position (where it can act as an abstract
> return type).
>
> ```
> trait Trait {}
>
> // argument position: anonymous type parameter
> fn foo(arg: impl Trait) {
> }
>
> // return position: abstract return type
> fn bar() -> impl Trait {
> }
> ```

Where [the grammar of `TypeParamBounds`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) allows both trait and lifetime bounds

> #### Trait and lifetime bounds
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> TypeParamBounds :
>    TypeParamBound ( + TypeParamBound )* +?
>
> TypeParamBound :
>       Lifetime | TraitBound
>
> TraitBound :
>       ?? ForLifetimes? TypePath
>    | ( ?? ForLifetimes? TypePath )
>
> LifetimeBounds :
>    ( Lifetime + )* Lifetime?
>
> Lifetime :
>       LIFETIME_OR_LABEL
>    | 'static
>    | '_
> ```

Particularly noting that the grammar of `TypeParamBounds` is one or optionally several `TypeParamBound`s combined, each of which in turn is either `TraitBound` or `Lifetime` (bounds).

[Specifying Multiple Trait Bounds with the + Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#specifying-multiple-trait-bounds-with-the--syntax) describe in some detail that we may combine more than one trait bound, but the same applies for lifetime bounds (where the grammar allows it). One could argue that the section should also mention lifetime bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely familiar, but logically it makes sense:

The function returns a Future that, when completed returns a byte. *When* the async fn is actually executed, it moves `x`, which is a reference with a lifetime. Technically `x` could be dropped before the Future is completed. To prevent this the lifetime trait guarantees that the return value of the function lives at least as long as `x`

Comment: Yes, the lifetime restraint does make senses here. Thanks for your answer. But I am more asking what it is, sorry for being ambiguous, will update my post.